# Upload the Large data from CSV file to Mysql inobdb table but i am getting error please help me

Tags: mysql

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE Upatentdata2 (
    Record_Number VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    Abstract LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    Record_Type VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Publication_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Application_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Estimated_Expiry_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Earliest_Priority_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Earliest_Publication_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Priority_Details VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Priority_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Application_No VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Application_No_Original VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Priority_Country_Code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Designated_States VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Field_of_search VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    Examiner VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Attorney VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PCT_Application_Number VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PCT_Patent_Number VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Claim LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    Description LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    Number_Of_Claims INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_Independent_Claims INT NOT NULL,
    Independent_Claims LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    First_Claim LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    Assignee_Normalized VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Assignee_Original VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Inventors VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Current_Assignee VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    First_Named_Inventor CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Applicant VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ICR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ICO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    US_Classes VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    CPC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FTERM VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Simple_Family_Members VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Simple_Family_Publication_Dates DATE NOT NULL,
    Simple_Family_ID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Simple_Family_Legal_Status_Current VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Extended_Family_Members VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Extended_Family_Publication_Dates DATE NOT NULL,
    Extended_Family_ID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Extended_Family_Legal_Status_Current VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Backward_Citation_Count INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_Forward_Citations INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_Forward_Citations_All_Simple_Family_Members INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_Forward_Citing_Families INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_non_self_citations_forward_citation INT NOT NULL,
    No_of_non_self_citations_backward_citation INT NOT NULL,
    Legal_Status_Current VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    INPADOC_Legal_Status VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    US_Reassignment_History VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    Current_Maintenance_Status_US VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    US_Maintenance_History VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    US_Additional_Info VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    Register_Link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PDF_Link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Backward_Citations VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Forward_Citations VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

My script for load data from terminal

```
select  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home
asir/Desktop/da1.csv'
    INTO  TABLE Upatentdata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
' IGNORE 1 ROWS (Record_Number,
                Title, Abstract, Record_Type, @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4,
                @var5, Priority_Details, @var6, Application_No, Application_No_Original,
                Priority_Country_Code, Designated_States, Field_of_search,
                Examiner, Attorney, PCT_Application_Number, PCT_Patent_Number,
                Claim, Description, Number_Of_Claims, No_of_Independent_Claims,
                Independent_Claims, First_Claim, Assignee_Normalized,
                Assignee_Original, Inventors, Current_Assignee, First_Named_Inventor,
                Applicant, ICR, ICO, US_Classes, CPC, FI, FTERM, Simple_Family_Members,
                @var7, Simple_Family_ID, Simple_Family_Legal_Status_Current,
                Extended_Family_Members, @var8, Extended_Family_ID, Extended_Family_Legal_Status_Current,
                Backward_Citation_Count, No_of_Forward_Citations, No_of_Forward_Citations_All_Simple_Family_Members,
                No_of_Forward_Citing_Families, No_of_non_self_citations_forward_citation,
                No_of_non_self_citations_backward_citation, Legal_Status_Current,
                INPADOC_Legal_Status, US_Reassignment_History, Current_Maintenance_Status_US,
                US_Maintenance_History, US_Additional_Info, Register_Link,
                PDF_Link, Backward_Citations, Forward_Citations) set Publication_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Application_Date =STR_TO_DATE(@var2,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Estimated_Expiry_Date =STR_TO_DATE(@var3,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Earliest_Priority_Date =STR_TO_DATE(@var4,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Earliest_Publication_Date =STR_TO_DATE(@var5,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Priority_Date =STR_TO_DATE(@var6, '%d-%b-%Y'
                ),
        set Simple_Family_Publication_Dates =STR_TO_DATE(@var7,
                '%d-%b-%Y'), set Extended_Family_Publication_Dates =STR_TO_DATE(@var8,
                '%d-%b-%Y'
                          );
```

But i am getting error like that

> ```
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;   
>     check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version   
>     for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
>     '/home/nasir/Desktop/da1.csv' INTO TABLE Upatentdata FIEL' at line 1
> ```

Please help me ?

Comment: `select` or  `LOAD`?

Answer (score 3):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is a statement unto itself.  No `SELECT` before it.

Notice how the 1064 pointed right at the point where the problem was.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html -- There can be only one `SET`, but it can include all the assignments.